# Recognize texts inside a red circle only

Tags: android-vision

I am using mobile vision api for text recognition. 
I want the app to only read the text inside a let's say red circle. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

MV API doesn't support that feature directly.

But you should be able to detect all texts, detect the red circle using [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Circle_detection_process), then check if these texts are in the circle since MV API reports the coordinates of the text.